# How can you loop evenly through entries using PDO & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, limit, offset

Ok I have done lots of searching to come up with this question. I have a set of 5 entries in my DB.

```
Entry 1 - Y
Entry 2 - N
Entry 3 - N
Entry 4 - N
```

What I want is to find where the Y is and jump to the next one. Once the Y gets to the end I want it start over. And I am using these 4 as an example. The amount of entries is constantly changing. Is there a way to do this? If so can someone tell me how? I am guessing some kind of OFFSET and LIMIT of 1 but I am not sure how to go about this. I have looking up SELECT statement variables etc but nothing I can use. Anyone have any idea?

Simplistically:  So when you access 1 it moves the Y to 2. and so on. Until the end where it moves the Y back to the beginning. Get it?

Here is where I started

**EDIT CODE UPDATED:**

```
<?php $finder = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Advertise WHERE Active='y' AND Called='n'");
    $finder->execute();
    $QCount = $finder->rowCount();
    if ($QCount > 1) {
        $update = $con->prepare("UPDATE Advertise SET Called='y' WHERE Active='y'");
        $update->execute();
        $update = $con->prepare("UPDATE Advertise SET Called='n' WHERE Active='y' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1");    
        $update->execute();
    }
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 9) {
        $finder = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Advertise WHERE Active='y' AND Called='n'");
        $finder->execute();
        $InfoGrab = $finder->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?> <a href="../Elements/Tracking.php?ID=<? echo $InfoGrab['ID']; ?>&URL=<? echo $InfoGrab['ALink']; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<? echo $InfoGrab['Picture']; ?>" alt="<? echo $InfoGrab['Business']; ?>" class="AdvertPic" /></a><br /><?

        $update = $con->prepare("UPDATE Advertise SET Called='y', Shown=Shown+1 WHERE ID='".$InfoGrab['ID']."'");
        $update->execute();
        $finder = $con->query("SELECT min(ID) FROM Advertise WHERE Active='y' AND Called='y' AND ID > '".$InfoGrab['ID']."' LIMIT 1");
        $finder->execute();
        $QCount = $finder->rowCount();
        if ($QCount == 0) {
            $update = $con->prepare("UPDATE Advertise SET Called='n' WHERE Active='y' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1");    
            $update->execute();
        }
        else {
            $update = $con->prepare("UPDATE Advertise SET Called='n' WHERE ID > '".$InfoGrab['ID']."' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1");    
            $update->execute();
        }
    $i++;
    }?>
```

**EDIT**:  Recently I have seen that in my list of 15 pictures maybe 12 and 13 are marked Active "N" so called is "N". Picture 14 and 15 are not being shown for some reason even though they are marked as Active="y". Is there an easier way to have my query search for each picture and display it one after the other as long as Active is "Y"? And also once it reaches the end of the amount it has to start over to fill in any empty space in the 9 spots.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column = 'Y'` I guess I dont undertand the question

Comment: @LeaTano So when you access 1 it moves the Y to 2. and so on. Until the end where it moves the Y back to the begeinning. Get it?

Comment: Got it. What did you do so far?  As SO guide states you need to show some work, please include your code.

Comment: @LeaTano Added code for you. Cause a loop and crash but kind of gets the idea